Why do I get Error while a Get request to url through Python Requests Lib
I am using requests library to get html content from a URL in which I have to pass consignment numbers comma separated which can be max 25 so when I send only 25 it works but when I send it in a loop it gives me connection time out error. I have tried HTTP.server also still same error.
    def get_html_content(self, cnn):
        url = f"https://tracking.dtdc.com/ctbs-tracking/customerInterface.tr?submitName=showCITrackingDetails&cType=Consignment&cnNo={cnn}"
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=A094634A72E33CE98B9548FF8E3E5871'
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.text
    

dtdc = DTDC(sql_username=sql_username,sql_database=sql_database,sql_password=sql_password,sql_server=sql_server)
##DTDC cong=signment number from SQL database
unfiltere_sqldata,sql_data = dtdc.sql_dtdc_data()

for i in range(0,len(sql_data['Docket No']),25): 
    print('Starting DTDC process')

    # dt
    print(sql_data.shape)
    dockets = ','.join(sql_data['Docket No'][i:i+25])

    html_contents = dtdc.get_html_content(cnn=dockets)
    if html_contents:
        print("HTML CONTENT SAVED")
    else:
        print("HTML CONTENT FAILED")

    tracking_df = dtdc.to_pddf(html_contents)
    print(tracking_df)

    Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
response = self._make_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
response = conn.getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 464, in getresponse
httplib_response = super().getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1390, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 325, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 294, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 667, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 474, in increment
raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
response = self._make_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
response = conn.getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 464, in getresponse
httplib_response = super().getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1390, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 325, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 294, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking\D_folder_shared\Logistics Tracking\main copy.py", line 87, in 
html_contents = dtdc.get_html_content(cnn=dockets)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking\D_folder_shared\Logistics Tracking\dtdcfunc.py", line 57, in get_html_content
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Rishav\OneDrive - JAY SWITCHES INDIA PVT LTD\Documents\Projects\Python\Logistics Tracking.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 682, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Edit the question and post the full error traceback message.
